# AngularJS и Javascript

Tags: angularjs

В качестве обертки значений во вьюшке, использую конструкцию со слэшами `// info //`. Проблема в том, что мне значение `// info //` необходимо использовать в javascript'e. А там `//` это начало комментария.

```
<script>
    var per = {value: // info //};
</script>
```

Как это можно обойти?

Comment: что значит _В качестве обертки значений во вьюшке_? как это все относится к ангуляру?

Comment: Это значит, что для вывода значений на странице  вместо  фигурных {{ 
info }} скобок я использую слэши // info //. На транице содержимое корректно отображается, только мне необходимо вывести info в javascript'e вставленном в страницу. Как видно из кода выше, часть строки у меня просто комментируется, в результате ява скрипт корректно не выполняется. Экранирование двойного слэша(\/\/ ino \/\/) не помогает.

Comment: все потому, что ты смешал все в кучу. если ты хочешь установить глобальную переменную так и устанавливай глобальную переменную, в коде ангуляра, когда будет доступно значение info.

Comment: Вы предлагаете сделать переменную info глобальной: $rootScope.info = response.data[0].information ? В моём случае погоды то это не меняет, т.к. работаю в одном контроллере. Вопрос скорее относится к тому, как вставить конструкцию // info // в javascript код, кот. просто работает на самой странице, а не в контроллере. Слэши в js это комментарии! Всё упирается в это)

Comment: Нет, глобальная, это глобальная: `window.per = {value: info};`

Answer (score 1):

Ангуляр - это обычный javascript код, и выполняется он после загрузки всей страницы.

Ошибка в данном случае в том, что код в теге скрипт выполняется браузером **до** того, как до него дойдет ангуляр.

Если нужна именно глобальная переменная `per`, ее и надо заполнять глобально:

```
// место где переменная info заполнена
window.per = { value: info}; // вместо глобальной переменной можно использовать сервис `$window`
```